# Annotating the vocabulary using Word2vec model

Tags: nlp, gensim, word2vec

I am trying to annotate the vocabulary in the corpus.

1. I have trained the word2vec model on the corpus
2. I have grouped the words which are related based on the score as key as the first word as the key and remaining words as a list of 2-tuple of word and scores with respect to the key

example:
'coffee'---key 
values are

```
[('tea', 0.8139282),
 ('latte', 0.76456803),
 ('coffe', 0.7607962),
 ('lattes', 0.756057),
 ('starbucks', 0.7158153),
 ('espresso', 0.71386236),
 ('mocha', 0.69999266),
 ('coffees', 0.6816252),
 ('frappucino', 0.67192864),
 ('cuppa', 0.66720986),
 ('cappucino', 0.6664002),
 ('chai', 0.6623157),
 ('decaf', 0.65980726),
 ('frappuccino', 0.65150374),
 ('venti', 0.6486204),
 ('expresso', 0.6369579),
 ('macchiato', 0.6280453),
 ('scone', 0.62476856),
 ('sippy', 0.6236704),
 ('cappuccino', 0.61718297),
 ('iced', 0.6130485),
 ('hazelnut', 0.6023698),
 ('mug', 0.6004759),
'
'
'
'
'
```

as i  know the coffee is releated to latte ,green_tea ,espresso,starbucks.. from the above data
I would like to label each word as below

latte [COHYPO] green_tea [COHYPO] espresso [HYPO] Starbucks [RELATED] tim_horton [RELATED]

COHYPO-https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cohyponym

[HYPO] -https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hyponyme

[RELATED] -the word is repeated

[MORPHO]-Morphological variant (example :Computer and computers )

[Partof]- indicates that the annotated word is a part of the word of interest

Any suggestion or ideas by which I can approach this problem

Comment: Can you check & clean up your question text formatting to make it clearer what's your text data, or tabular data, or desired output? Note also that word2vec at base only gives a single scalar value for the similarity between 2 words - with no further qualification of kind(s) of similarity present. So alone, it's not enough to distinguish hypernymy/hyponymy, synonymy/antonyms (even antonyms are very "similar" in word2vec space), holonyms/meronyms, & other subtle word relationships. (Often directions in word2vec space are vaguely interpretable, but not usually in linguistically-precise ways.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @gojomo  I have made changes to my question. are there ways to label them as above by using another way

Comment: I'm not familiar with any reliable off-the-shelf technique – certainly not using plain word2vec, because as previously mentioned, its sense of similarity (and relative directions) isn't nearly as fine-grained as you want to label these words. There are certainly research papers about things like discovering synonymity, or hyponym relations, from texts – but in some cases these work for looking for indicative phrases, like "X, and other Ys" or "X is a kind of Y".